# Adding two JPanels to JFrame, only one is visible

Tags: java, swing

[image: Game]

I have the following problem, when i want to add 2JPanels to my JFrame only one is visible, depending on which I added to the frame last. I overrided the JPanels default paintComponent() method on both of the JPanels. How can i fix this?

Code snippet:
Border:

```
public class BorderDrawer extends JPanel{
    private int _width,_height;

    BorderDrawer(int width,int height)
    {
        setOpaque(false);
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 20,BUTTON_HEIGHT = 20;
        int MINES_HORIZONTALLY = _width;
        int MINES_VERTICALLY = _height;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        try{
            BufferedImage topLeftCorner = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("topLeftCorner.png"));
            g.drawImage(topLeftCorner, 0, 0, null); 
            ....// drawing other border components
    }
}
```

Clock:

```
public class GraphicTimer extends JPanel{
    Timer _aktTimer = null;
    int seconds;
    int _width = 0;
    GraphicTimer(int width)
    {
        setSize(52, 31);
        setOpaque(false);
        _width = width;
        int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
        _aktTimer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        try
        {
            final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 20,BUTTON_HEIGHT = 20;
            int MINES_HORIZONTALLY = _width;
            int HORIZONTAL_ENDING = 15+BUTTON_WIDTH*MINES_HORIZONTALLY;

            BufferedImage clock = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("clock.png"));
            g.drawImage(clock,HORIZONTAL_ENDING-54,22, null);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     ....
}
```

JFrame:

```
public class DrawerField extends JFrame implements Serializable{  
    //...
    public DrawerField() 
    {
        super("MineSweeper");
        _FIELD = new Field();
        constructorInit();
    }
    public void constructorInit()
    {        
        _buttons = new FieldButton[_height][_width];  
        _isMouseEventEnabled = true;
        fieldPanel = new JPanel();
        smilePanel = new JPanel();
        //INITS
        int fieldSizeWidth = (_width)*20;
        int fieldSizeHeight = (_height)*20; // Magic size
        fieldPanel.setSize(fieldSizeWidth,fieldSizeHeight); // 20x20 
        fieldPanel.setLocation(15, 70);
        fieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(_width,_height)); 
        int fullWindowWidth = fieldSizeWidth+36;
        int fullWindowHeight = fieldSizeHeight+142;
        setSize(fullWindowWidth,fullWindowHeight);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        restartButton = new RestartButton(this);
        smilePanel.setSize(34,34);                    
        smilePanel.add(restartButton);
        smilePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));  
        smilePanel.setLocation((int)fullWindowWidth/2-(34/2)-1,20);
        ///INITIALS

        for(int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < _width ; j++)
            {
                    _buttons[i][j] = new FieldButton(_hidden[i][j],true,i,j,this);
                    fieldPanel.add(_buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }

        add(smilePanel);
        add(fieldPanel);

        borderDrawer = new BorderDrawer(_width,_height);
        _graphicTimer = new GraphicTimer(_width);
        _graphicTimer.start();


        add(_graphicTimer);  // This is the two lines which change the result
        add(borderDrawer);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar(this);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    //...
}
```

Easier and compilable example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        MyPanel panel1 = new MyPanel(30,30);
        frame.add(panel1);
        MyPanel panel2 = new MyPanel(70,30);
        frame.add(panel2);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.repaint();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class MyPanel extends JPanel
    {
        int _x,_y;
        MyPanel(int x, int y)
        {
            _x = x; _y = y;
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {


            g.drawOval(_x,_y,20,20);
        }
    }
}
```

My main goal is to add 2 circles to the JFrame without using any Layout.( As you can see in the example above I already have a lot of things on my JFrame that's why I don'T want to use layouts). The problem is the same in this example, when i add the 2nd circle the first is disappearing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  As for the panels, have one red panel & one blue panel.

Comment: Tried `repaint()` and `revalidate()` ?

Comment: Remove all the painting and show how you add 2 panels to a frame.

Comment: borderDrawer = new BorderDrawer(_width,_height);
        _graphicTimer = new GraphicTimer(_width);

        add(_graphicTimer);  // This is the two lines which change the result
        add(borderDrawer);

Jframe is using the default layout, graphicTimer, and borderDrawer are my own JPanels.

Comment: `add(smilePanel);
        add(fieldPanel);`  BTW - A `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` by default.  A component added to a border layout with no constraint defaults to `CENTER`.  Each of the 5 areas of a border layout can display precisely 1 component.  It would 'work' if instead it were.. `add(smilePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);` ..  Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: Put the relevant code in your question, not in comments.

Comment: Don't use underscores, `_`, in your variable names. It is not in line with the Java naming conventions.

Comment: I'm getting 69 compilation errors. Once you get it down to 0, repost the code that we can run.

Comment: thank you for your efforts, I created a simplier example ( added to the end of the post)

Answer (score 2):

Its simple. Adding a panel in a frame adds it to the `content pane` of the frame. This contentpane has a default layout of `BorderLayout` which means, every time you add a panel, it gets added to the center of the content pane and gets replaces the previous one. This is the reason why you see only the last one. Its always good to use a Jpanel set to the layout of your choice put everything that needs to be shown on the screen in that panel. If you don't want to do that, you may also call `getContentPane()` from the frame and play with the returned instance of `JPanel`.

Comment: I have tried to get the content pane, and add them to it, but the result was the same. 
Would you be so nice to show me how you imagined it in the easier example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example code for you:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public Frame() {
        setTitle("Two panels");
        setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Here goes your code
        JPanel p= (JPanel) getContentPane();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2)); //set your own layout
        p.add(new MyPanel(Color.BLUE)); //add panel with blue border
        p.add(new MyPanel(Color.GREEN));//add panel with green border
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Frame f= new Frame();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyPanel(Color color) {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color));
    }
}
```

Run it and see... You should be able to see something like this:

[image: Frame with two panels]

Comment: as i already said it in the post, I don't/can't use layouts to solve the problem because i have a lot of other panels too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: hey, you needn't set the layout every time you add panels to them. Just set it once somewhere, then keep adding or removing panels. In your easier example, just add the line `((JPanel)getContentPane()).setLayout()` before adding panels to the frame. It will work.